# How to put variable in JSON URL?

Tags: php

Tried a lot of combinations but nothing works.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/58424d43204d6564696120/search.php?s=$artist");
```

Comment: _What_ doesn't work?

Comment: For debugging purposes: Save the URL in a variable first and output it. Check that the URL is correct. After that edit your question to include the full source code you have and the error message you get.

Comment: the variable i don't know how to place the variable $artist

Comment: Looks fine to me. The only other thing I'd do is make sure it's encoded correctly for use in a URL, ie `...search.php?s=" . urlencode($artist)`

Comment: Thanks it works!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that wouldn't *"work"* is if the `$artist` variable contained characters not suitable for use in a URL (like spaces, punctuation, etc).

PHP has a function that can make strings safe for use in a URL ~ [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)...

```
$artist = 'Pink Floyd'; // spaces should be encoded as "%20" or "+"
$json = file_get_contents(sprintf(
    'http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/58424d43204d6564696120/search.php?s=%s', 
    urlencode($artist)));
```